# bash to parse XML into multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, xml, linux, bash, parsing

I have a XML file which I want to parse into bash variables/arrays.
I have limited linux commands (busybox) available since I am working on a NAS box.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> . 
<WEBCAMS>  
<CAM>  
            <DESCRIPTION>description for cam 1</DESCRIPTION>
            <URL>http://myURLtoWebcam1/cam1/pic.jpg</URL>
            <FILENAME>filename1</FILENAME>   
</CAM>  
<CAM>  
            <DESCRIPTION>description for cam 2</DESCRIPTION>
            <URL>http://myURLtoWebcam2/cam2/pic.jpg</URL>
            <FILENAME>filename2</FILENAME>   
</CAM>   
</WEBCAMS>
```

my bash script so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
rdom () { local IFS=\> ; read -d \< E C ;}
while rdom; do
if [[ $E = DESCRIPTION ]]; then
        counter=$((counter+1))
        declare cam$counter="$C"
fi

done < webcams.xml
```

I want to get the XML content like the following:

```
echo "Cam1 description: ${cam1[0]}";  ## should show: description for cam 1
echo "Cam1 URL: ${cam1[1]}"; ## should show: http://myURLtoWebcam1/cam1/pic.jpg
echo "Cam1 filename: ${cam1[2]}"; should show: filename1

echo "Cam2 description: ${cam2[0]}"; ## should show: description for cam 2
echo "Cam2 URL: ${cam2[1]}"; ## should show: http://myURLtoWebcam1/cam2/pic.jpg
echo "Cam2 filename: ${cam2[2]}"; ## should show: filename2
```

So far I am only able to read the "DESCRIPTION" fields into bash variables.
Any idea how to get the other fields "URL" and "FILENAME" into my arrays/variables? The so far found solutions did not fit or could not be modified to my needs due to the limited Linux commands on my NAS.

Comment: Wait. Do you have a busybox shell, or do you have bash? (`#!/bin/sh` is generally something like busybox's implementation of `ash` on systems using it; even on systems where it's a symlink to bash, though, it goes into less-featureful POSIX-only mode when invoked as `sh`). If you really have bash, and you want to be able to use bash-only syntax, your shebang should be something like `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Beyond that -- **exactly** what other software do you have on that system? It's not uncommon to have a real XML parser hidden somewhere (in an interpreted-language runtime such as Python, or installed in a shell-accessible helper via a native dependency such as libxml2) even on a quite small system. An answer that uses such a parser will be far less bug-prone (having integration partners break when changes that *shouldn't* harm their code break hand-written consumers is very tiresome, and folks who've had the experience tend to have little patience for questions asking to parse XML badly).

Comment: BTW, `IFS=\> read -d \< E C` (with no semicolon or newline) sets `IFS` only for the scope of the one `read` command; there's no need to try to play around with function locals or the like.

Comment: I didn't see your comment until now because you put it on someone else's answer instead of here -- `rdom () { local IFS=\> ; read -d \< E C ;}` is trying to define IFS as a function local, but that's needless: You can set IFS local to the individual `read` command by just taking out the `;` between that and the `read`, and removing the `local` keyword. `var=val somecommand` runs `somecommand` with `var` temporarily exported in the environment as `val`.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you by adding my comments on the wrong place. Now I got your hint. I changed the first line of my code to `rdom () { IFS=\> read -d \< E C; }` which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If XSLTPROC is available you can use it - bonus its a real XML parser.

```
> xsltproc transform.xsl webcams.xml 

Cam1 description: description for cam 1
Cam1 URL: http://myURLtoWebcam1/cam1/pic.jpg
Cam1 filename: filename1
Cam2 description: description for cam 2
Cam2 URL: http://myURLtoWebcam2/cam2/pic.jpg
Cam2 filename: filename2
```

Where transform.xsl is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="CAM">
  <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
Cam<xsl:value-of select="$i"/> description: <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
Cam<xsl:value-of select="$i"/> URL: <xsl:value-of select="URL"/>
Cam<xsl:value-of select="$i"/> filename: <xsl:value-of select="FILENAME"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="/WEBCAMS"><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu) but limited commands around. Unfortunately no XML parser.

Comment: Charles what do you mean with your latest comment about my IFS usage? Especially I do not understand your statement: "there's no need to try to play around with function locals or the like"

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ... but still the 1,5D dimensional array or the way to escape variables makes me headache - see below problems within a FOR loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
rdom () { local IFS=\> ; read -d \< E C ;}
while rdom; do
if [[ $E = DESCRIPTION ]]; then
        counter0=$((counter0+1))
        declare -a cam$((counter0))[0]="$C"
fi

if [[ $E = URL ]]; then
        counter1=$((counter1+1))
        declare -a cam$((counter1))[1]="$C"
fi

if [[ $E = FILENAME ]]; then
        counter2=$((counter2+1))
        declare -a cam$((counter2))[2]="$C"
fi

done < webcams.xml

echo "Cam1 description: ${cam1[0]}";
echo "Cam1 URL: ${cam1[1]}";
echo "Cam1 filename: ${cam1[2]}";

echo "Cam2 description: ${cam2[0]}";
echo "Cam2 URL: ${cam2[1]}";
echo "Cam2 filename: ${cam2[2]}";
```

But it is still impossible to get the values within a FOR loop like:

```
for (( c=1; c<=$counter0; c++ ))
do
        var=cam$c;
        echo "Cam$c description: ${!var[0]}";
        echo "Cam$c URL: ${!var[1]}";
        echo "Cam$c filename: ${!var[2]}";
done
```

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd have an array for descriptions, an array for URLs, and an array for filenames. That way you *can* trivially have your `for` loop.

Comment: For my purpose I need an array for every cam - each array containing 3 fields: DESCRIPTION, URL and FILENAME. Later the amount of cams (arrays) differs.

Comment: The number of cams differing sounds like an extremely compelling reason to have exactly three arrays with the number of elements differing, not the other way around.

Comment: If you had it that way, you could do this: `for idx in "${!descriptions[@]}"; do echo "description: ${descriptions[$idx]}, url: ${urls[$idx]}; filename: ${filenames[$idx]}`; done` -- very clean, very simple.

Comment: I changed (added eval for the array) the above FOR loop which after all looks also very simple?  
`for (( c=1; c<=$counter0; c++ ))
do
        eval var=( '"${cam'${c}'[@]}"' );
        echo "Cam$c description: ${var[0]}";
        echo "Cam$c URL: ${var[1]}";
        echo "Cam$c filename: ${var[2]}";
done`

Comment: Ewwwww (re: `eval`). Consider using namevars instead.

Comment: ...actually, strike that, bash 3.2 is too old -- they aren't an available feature there. Still, mucking around with `eval` is frowned on as a practice -- it means someone auditing your code needs to pay far more attention to the variables going into the string thus processed.

Comment: Consider: `printf -v eval_str 'var=( "${cam%d[@]}" )' "$c" && eval "$eval_str"` -- that way the quoting is more obvious, and any attempt at a non-numeric substitution causes an explicit error.

Comment: (I still don't understand *why* you'd have a variable number of variables, rather than a fixed number of arrays with a variable number of indices -- this contravenes good practice in not just bash but a wide variety of other languages; I could point to any number of folks asking how to dynamically create and resolve variables in Python, for example, and being told "don't").

Comment: Using only three arrays also would let you entirely drop the counter variables: `descriptions+=( "$C" )` appends to the end of the array, no explicit index needed, and thus no more need for `counter0`, `counter1` and `counter2`.